# How can I scroll to a DIV's child element consistently across browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a test case here:

http://www.libsys.und.edu/dev/scroll-test.html

It has a DIV containing a very long list of links.  I want to scroll the DIV down to a given link.  In my test case, that's done by pressing the JSTOR button, which advances it to the JSTOR link.  In an actual production sample, the link would be chosen based on keyboard input.  So, for example, pressing "B" would advance it to the first "B" link, Biological Abstracts.

The expected results in my test case are: I click JSTOR, and it scrolls so JSTOR is at the top of the DIV.  That might involve scrolling down or up, depending on how far the DIV has been scrolled already.

The actual results depend on whether the DIV has already been scrolled at all.

If the DIV has *not* been scrolled at all, then it works correctly in all browsers.

If the DIV has been scrolled already (even a little bit), the results are as follows:

1. Firefox scrolls down and places JSTOR at the *bottom* of the DIV.
2. Chrome scrolls down and places JSTOR at the *bottom* of the DIV. (but see below)
3. Safari scrolls down and places JSTOR at the *bottom* of the DIV. (but see below)
4. Chrome scrolls down and places JSTOR at the *bottom* of the DIV.
5. Opera scrolls down and places JSTOR at the *top* of the DIV.

Additionally, under some circumstances that I have not been able to satisfactorily identify, both Chrome and Safari will scroll down and place the JSTOR link centered vertically in the *middle* of the DIV.

Opera is the only browser that consistently does what I was expecting.  Firefox and IE do it differently, but at least do it *consistently* differently, and their behavior matches one another; I don't know what to make of Chrome and Safari's behavior.

So -- is there some way to scroll the DIV in such a way that the targeted link always winds up in the same position relative to its parent across browsers?  I don't even care if it's at the top, really, though that makes the most sense to me.  As long as I can get it to work the same way consistently, I'll be happy.

For the long-term record, here's my CSS and JS; the HTML is just a really long list of links inside a DIV with the ID "box".  I tried to make a JS Fiddle out of this, but it died on me -- I think it didn't like the length of the HTML source.

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#box ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

JS:

```
// I'm running scrollTop() and position().top through Math.floor() because
// Firefox likes reporting fractional values for pixels, for some reason.
function reportOffsets(){
    var offset = Math.floor($("#box").scrollTop());
    var position = Math.floor($("#jstor").position().top);
    $("#counter").html(offset+"px; J "+position+"px");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // When the box scrolls, tell me its current offset and where JSTOR is.
    $("#box").scroll(reportOffsets);

    $("#go").click(function(e){
        // Get the current position of the JSTOR link.
        var position = Math.floor($("#jstor").position().top);

        // Scroll the box down to it.
        $("#box").scrollTop(position);

        $("#jstor").focus();

        reportOffsets();
    });

    reportOffsets();
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DOM method [`scrollIntoView()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t23) should be exactly what you want. There is an [optional alignWithTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView) parameter which defaults to `true`. If you use `false` (as in the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YeY8n/1/)) the element aligns with the bottom instead.

Comment: Interesting!  I will try that out, and if it works I'll accept the answer.  EDIT:  And it works very smoothly.  Thanks!  I've been banging my head against that all day.

Comment: Happy to help! It's a good question and I like trying to solve problems like this +1 :)

Comment: how about adding smooth scrolling to it?

Comment: There is experimental support for [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)  `scrollViewOptions` in FF only, so `.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});` works nicely but only in FF. Alternatively, if you can use jQuery there is a plugin as answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/12105126/637889

Comment: Even though the MDN documentation says it's experimental, it seems to me [well implemented in most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview) ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use an anchor. // extra junk for SO

#### Edit

Below is an anchor based solution so show what I was talking about. The original post was a bit brief. It doesn't work in IE for some reason, it just doesn't see the anchor. So the *scrollIntoView* solution is best as it seems to work back to IE 6 at least.

Pass the element to scroll to to *inPageNav*. It puts an anchor immediately before it in the DOM, then adds an anchor name to the URL to go there. Inserting an anchor has no effect on the page layout.

The function only creates one anchor and moves it to the required location each time so quite efficient. But not as good as *scrollIntoView*.

```
var inPageNav = (function() {

  // Store the anchor
  var anchor;
  var anchorHref;

  return function(el) {

    var anchorName;

    // Create an anchor if don't already have one
    if (!anchor) {
      anchor = document.createElement('a');
      anchorName = 'foo' + (new Date().getTime()); 
      anchor.name = anchorName;
      anchorHref = document.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'') +  
                                             '#' + anchorName;
    }

    // Move anchor and go there
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(anchor, el);
    document.location.href = anchorHref;
  }
}());
```

Comment: -1 for not reading the goal described at the end of the paragraph after the test case -- to scroll to an arbitrary link selected based on its first letter in response to keyboard input. An anchor is not even close to the same functionality.

Comment: The server can create anchors to meet whatever requirement the OP wants using exactly the same logic as the client would, such as creating a B anchor at the top of the Bs, C anchor at the top of the Cs, whatever. Or anchors can be created dynamically on the client - insert an anchor and then adjust the URL.

Comment: The overall purpose is to add keyboard navigation to a similar but more advanced list, which you can see by visiting http://new.und.edu/ and opening the Quick Links.  After the pane is open, pressing a letter jumps to the first link of that letter.  The point is to avoid making people click on stuff; it's a shortcut for advanced users.  I'm still working on the functionality to skip ahead to further links with the same letter in response to repeated keystrikes.  For example, press B once and get Biological Abstracts; press B twice and get Biomed Central; and so on. Anchors won't cut it.